# Clojure convert currency string to float

Tags: clojure, string-parsing

I know that there's a lot of questions about converting string to float/number/decimal... but my case is quite different cause I need to convert the string number (representing a dollar value) but I must keep the cents in this conversion, here is my case.

I receive this values
"96,26" 
"1.296,26"
And I expect to convert to this follow:
96.26
1296.26

If I try to use clojure.edn it escape cents

```clj
(edn/read-string "1.296,26")
=> 1.296
```

```clj
(edn/read-string "96,26")
=> 96
```

If I try to use another approach like bugdec I get NumberFormatException

I know that we can do some string replace but it looks like a big work around, like this:

```
(-> "1.296,87"
    (clojure.string/replace #"\." "")
    (clojure.string/replace #"," ".")
    (edn/read-string))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you can do, is to use java's formatting facilities:

```
(defn read-num [s]
  (let [format (java.text.NumberFormat/getNumberInstance java.util.Locale/GERMANY)]
    (.parse format s)))

user> (read-num "1.296,26")
;;=> 1296.26

user> (read-num "96,26")
;;=> 96.26
```

Comment: To be really picky, the double precision floating point representation of 96.26 may not be exactly 96.26. To obtain an *exact* representation of the value 96.26, one could maybe convert it to a ratio using a function such as `(defn fraction-of-100 [x] (/ (Math/round (* 100 x)) 100))`.

Comment: Try for example `(- 96.26 (- (+ 96.26 100000) 100000))` in the REPL.

Comment: See `DecimalFormat` and `DecimalFormatSymbols` if you need exact values.

Answer (score 4):

Just use straight Java interop:

```
(let [nf (java.text.NumberFormat/getInstance java.util.Locale/FRENCH)]

  (.parse nf "12,6")) => 12.6
```

See the Oracle docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html

and this posting:  https://www.baeldung.com/java-decimalformat

---

You can also get a `BigDecimal` to avoid any rounding errors.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols)

```
  (let [nf     (DecimalFormat. "" (DecimalFormatSymbols. Locale/ITALIAN))
        >>     (.setParseBigDecimal nf true)
        result (.parse nf "123.45,9")]

  result => <#java.math.BigDecimal 12345.9M>
```